# Preserving special characters when writing to a CSV - What encoding to use?

Tags: python, csv, utf-8, cp1252

I am trying to save the string `the United Nations’ Sustainable Development Goals (SDGs)` into a csv.

**If I use utf-8 as the encoding, the apostrophe in the string gets converted to an ASCII char**

```
import csv
str_ = "the United Nations’ Sustainable Development Goals (SDGs)"

#write to a csv file
with open("output.csv", 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(file,delimiter=",")
    csv_writer.writerow([str_])

#read from the csv file created above
with open("output.csv",newline='') as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file)

    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row)
```

The result I get is
`['the United Nationsâ€™ Sustainable Development Goals (SDGs)']`

**If I use cp1252 as the encoding, the apostrophe in the string is preserved as you can see in the result**

```
import csv
str_ = "the United Nations’ Sustainable Development Goals (SDGs)"

#write to a csv file
with open("output.csv", 'w', newline='', encoding='cp1252') as file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(file,delimiter=",")
    csv_writer.writerow([str_])

#read from the csv file created above
with open("output.csv",newline='') as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file)

    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row)
```

The result I get is
`['the United Nations' Sustainable Development Goals (SDGs)']` , which is ideal and

**What encoding should I ideally be using if I want to preserve the special characters ? Is there a benefit of using utf-8 over cp1252?**

My use case is to feed lines in the CSV to a language model(GPT) and hence I want the text to be "English" /  Unchanged..

I am using Python 3.8 on Windows 11

Comment: Hello! In general, utf-8 is recommended because it can handle a wider range of characters and is the most widely used character encoding on the web. However, the encoding to use depends on your specific use case and the characters you need to represent.

Comment: The issue you encountered with the apostrophe being converted to an ASCII character might have been due to some other factors, such as the encoding of the original text source

Comment: If you choose to offer us a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), some SO contributor might choose to offer a relevant answer.

Comment: I've replicate your problem and I've eliminated the `encoding='utf-8'` param to preserve the `’` symbol. `with open('outputfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:` I'm not sure if this is  what you are looking for.

Comment: in [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-locale-encoding)  says in windows the dafault encoding is ANSI: `On Windows, it is the ANSI code page (ex: "cp1252").`

Comment: @StandardIO , does the line you have quoted in the documentation mean that on windows python uses "cp1252" by default ?

Comment: @newbie101 that's right. In Windows `cp1252`  and, in Linux and Android use `utf-8` (I've provided the direct link).

Comment: @AyushNaik I don't think it's an issue with the original text source.. I have now added a reproducible code in my question.. The source for the text is no document.. I create the sting directly in python as you can see..

Comment: @J_H I have added a fully reproducible code now..

Comment: @newbie101 it seems that the issue is not with the encoding itself, but with the way the CSV file is being read and displayed. You need specify the encoding explicitly when reading the CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("output.csv", 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    ...

with open("output.csv",newline='') as file:
    ...
```

The problem is simply that you're explicitly, correctly writing UTF-8 to the file, but then open it for reading in some undefined implicit encoding, which in your case defaults to *not UTF-8*. Thus you're *reading* it wrong.

Also include the encoding when reading the file, and all is good:

```
with open('output.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
```

You *should* use UTF-8 as encoding, as it can encode all possible characters. Most other encodings can only encode some subset of all possible characters. You'd need to have a good reason to use another encoding. If you have a particular target in mind (e.g. Excel) and you know what encoding that target prefers, then use that. Otherwise UTF-8 is a sane default.

Comment: Ohh no, my bad. It was an oversight on my part. Thanks!